# Tomcat JNDI + Standalone Java

Tags: java, tomcat7, jndi

All,

I understand that one can't access Tomcat's JNDI provider from outside Tomcat i.e, can't use a stand-alone java class to invoke the tomcat jndi. But this was in older version tomcat 5 and 6

Does anyone here has an idea if this is feasible with the latest versions staring from Tomcat7? If so, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has changed. Objects in the java: namespace are only accessible from within the container as a rule.